# How do I connect to a cheap wifi (wemos) relay board?

Tags: relay, wifi, esp8266

I got a cheap wifi relay board off wish.com and I want to connect it to my network. When I apply power (no less than 12v) I can see AI-THINKER_xxxxxx when I attempt to connect to it, I'm asked for a password. There was no documentation supplied with the device - how am I supposed to guess the default password to connect to the device. I want to use a smart phone app like Smart life (or anything that will work) to connect the device to my amazon echo. I got cheap RGB LEDs from the same place, but at least it came with a password - this relay board came with nothing and I cant seem to find anything out there on setup.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but providing answers on undocumented modules is not the role of this site.  Try a web search, or demand answers from the seller, or if it is actually an esp8266 reflash it from scratch - and next time make sure you have answers to the obvious questions *before* you buy.

Comment: you can reflash the ESP01 module with arduino, lua, micropython, even JS.

Answer (score 1):

wtmrapsody        = password ................................

http://www.axelprod.net/download/WTM_RAPSODi/gb_WTM_868_1660_RAPSODY_product_description_r1_02.pdf